# Mysql move characters around inside strings

Tags: mysql

Just wondering if it is possible in Mysql to move characters inside a string without having to resort to PHP, etc.

Example:

Blue Dahlia, The

Has to become "The Blue Dahlia". So remove the comma and move the "the" after it to the beginning. Removing the comma could be done with:

```
... SET field = REPLACE(field, CHAR(47), '')
```

But moving the "the" to the beginning seems daunting to me since I just can't replace all the instances of "the", only the one after the last comma.

This is easily done with PHP but I was wondering if I could do it in SQL, since it's (hopefully) a one-time thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
... SET field = CONCAT_WS(' ', TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ',', -1)), TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ',', 1)))
```

Quick explanation:

`SUBSTRING_INDEX` splits string by delimiter. `-1` takes first part from the right; `1` first from the left.

`TRIM` removes unnecessary whitespaces.

`CONCAT_WS` merges parts of string with spacebar separator.

Comment: Wow, this actually works. I thought it would be impossible without an external scripting language. Thank you so much!